# Bash: Retain variable's value after while loop

Tags: bash

I need to retain the value of `TEMP_FLAG` after my while loop ends.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMP_FLAG=false

# loop over git log and set variable
git log --pretty="%H|%s" --skip=1 |
    while read commit; do 

        # do stuff like parsing the commit...

        # set variable     
        TEMP_FLAG=true 
    done

echo "$TEMP_FLAG" # <--- evaluates to false :(
```

I know that my issue is caused by piping the `git log` to the while loop, which spawns a subshell that doesn't give back my updated variable.

However, is there a way get my intended behavior without changing the pipe?

Comment: You cannot use pipe if you want to retain variables outside. Use process substitution

Comment: At all? I've seen things like `done <<< (something)` that seem to provide a way to receive variables that have been changed in a piped while loop

Comment: @DannyDelott right, but that doesn't use the pipe, which is key.  Pipes create subshells and a subshell cannot modify its parent's environment

Comment: @anubhava: Does that line imply removing the original `git log ... | `

Comment: BTW, this is BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: My issue was using `sh` instead of `bash` to launch my script, along with the rule about piping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a pipe you are automatically creating subshells so that the input and output can be hooked up by the shell.  That means that you cannot modify the parent environment, because you're now in a child process.

As anubhava said though, you can reformulate the loop to avoid the pipe by using process substitution like so:

```
while read commit; do
    TEMP_FLAG=true
done < <( git log --pretty="%H|%s" --skip=1 )

printf "%s\n" "$TEMP_FLAG"
```

Comment: This gives me: `line 36: syntax error near unexpected token \`<' `

Comment: @DannyDelott, that means your shell isn't bash. Be sure your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, and that you aren't running it with `sh yourscript`.

Comment: Hm, I'm using `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my script.

Comment: @DannyDelott, and you're starting the script how?

Comment: I am running it with `sh myscript.sh` though, how should it be run?

Comment: `bash myscript.sh`, though you shouldn't use a `.sh` extension for something that isn't a POSIX sh script. (Common practice is for executable commands to have no extension at all -- you don't run `ls.elf`, after all -- but if something is a shell *library*, then it should be `.bash` if it's for bash, `.ksh` for ksh, etc., and `.sh` only for POSIX sh).

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected now.